# The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured while running Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse

```
[2014-04-02 12:30:28 - EsrtDummyproject1] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2014-04-02 12:30:28 - EsrtDummyproject1] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2014-04-02 12:30:28 - EsrtDummyproject1] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at 'C:\Tulika\SOFTWARES\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\platform-tools\adb.
```

I tried all the ways to solve it.

1. I have killed the adb.exe process from Task manager.
2. Restarted eclipse.
3. But still facing with the same issue.

Can anyone help resolving it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps:

1. Close the Eclipse if running
2. Go to the Android SDK platform-tools directory in Command Prompt
3. type adb `kill-server`
4. then type adb `start-server`
5. No error message is thrown while starting ADB server, then adb is started successfully.
6. Now you can start Eclipse again.

it worked for me this way, Eclipse should be closed before issuing these commands.

Restart your phone as well!

Answer (score 0):

It happens sometimes if you use more than one instances of eclipse

To repair logging do:

```
1. Unplug the device
2. Close all Eclipse windows
3. Restart adb in command line: adb kill-server and than adb start-server
4. Run again Eclipse and connect device
```

Sometimes this also helps, Go to Eclipse Window > Perspective > DDMS and than from Device sub-window choose Reset adb